# Can Dart runs jar archive?

Tags: java, jar, dart

I need to run stanford-parser.jar from Dart and use its methods to POS tag user input. Is this feasible on Dart?

Answer (score 3):

No, Dart is not Java. There is a Java to Dart source code transformation experiment available here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fdart%2Feditor%2Futil%2Fplugins%2Fcom.google.dart.java2dart